# Passing data to control from kentico transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, kentico

I am trying to pass the value of a custom table field that is retrieved via a transformation in kentico cms to a custom user control.

To explain my setup, inside my master file I have a QueryUniView control that calls the transformation "SelectedStoreInformation". Inside of this transformation I have markup and I am able to print out the field I am looking for just fine using:

```
<%# Eval("StoreCodeName") %>
```

However I am in need to pass this value to a custom user control and want to be able to check the value in the code behind. So I proceeded to add a property to the code behind and set this property on the server tag itself assuming that the value would pass through.

Property on custom control code behind:

```
public string StoreName { get; set; }
```

Server tag include (this is in the transformation to pull in the custom control):

```
<cms:Hours ID="Hours" StoreName='<%# Eval("StoreCodeName") %>' runat="server" />
```

However the StoreName is null in the code behind. If I change the value of StoreName on the tag to just a static string of text it works fine.

My confusion is why does the Eval of the field work when I place it right above the server tag but does not work in the server tag?

Thanks for any help, sorry for the long question.

Kentico v6

Comment: My control code behind class inherits from CMSAbstractWebPart

Comment: It's not that the Eval does not work in the server tag - it's probably just evaluated later. Check that you don't access the property too early. I suggest to use its value in OnDataBinding or OnPreRender.

Comment: @rocky That did it! Thank you very much. I feel like I have been beating my head over this for several days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that the Eval does not work in the server tag - it's probably just evaluated later. Check that you don't access the property too early. I suggest to use its value in OnDataBinding or OnPreRender.